# How to find the average of 3 weeks

Tags: average

I am trying to get the average rate in total for weeks (43,44,45) and (47,48,49) and compare to week 46.
So I am looking for one average rate (in total) for weeks 43-45, then again (47-49).  How can I do this?
SELECT
week, code, count(case when on_time = '1' then 1 else null end) *1.0 / count(*) as arrived
FROM table
where Week in ('43','44','45','46','47','48', '49') and code in ('GAL',
'DRA');

Where would I add in to get the avg rate for arrived for the two buckets of weeks(listed above)?

Comment: May you please tell what you're trying to do with the `count(case when on_time = '1' then 1 else null end) 1.0 / count() `? Isn't the averate of a field called `rate` thus get the average of such field?

Comment: I was trying to calculate the arrived metric, as it is not something that comes from the data.  To find the ARRIVED RATE for my data I have to divide # of on time arrivals/total arrivals.  Once I have the arrival calculated for each code for each week, I would like the average of that rate for each code.

Answer (score 0):

You can group per week, considering the week 46 as a single item group. After that you extract the average of each group by casting the `on_time` value this way:

```sql
SELECT
    (
        CASE WHEN week IN ('43', '44', '45') THEN
            'w1'
        WHEN week IN ('47', '48', '49') THEN
            'w2'
        ELSE
            '46'
        END) week_group,
    code,
    (sum(
            CASE WHEN on_time = '1' THEN
                1
            ELSE
                0
            END) / count()) AS on_time_rate
FROM
    TABLE
WHERE
    Week IN ('43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49')
    AND code IN ('GAL', 'DRA')
GROUP BY
    (
        CASE WHEN week IN ('43', '44', '45') THEN
            'w1'
        WHEN week IN ('47', '48', '49') THEN
            'w2'
        ELSE
            '46'
        END);
```